# VS2015 Several projects throwing exceptions before main

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I have several projects that were created in VS 2010 but have recently been updated to VS 2015.  All of them compile OK, but many of them now throw an exception before reaching main:

```
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\kloux\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BandwidthCruncher\Debug\MyApp.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sysfer.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MyApp.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown at 0x74F4C42D in MyApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::exception at memory location 0x0032F3EC.
Exception thrown at 0x74A17780 (sysfer.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000010.
```

I can always choose "Continue," in the resulting dialog, and the application seems to run without issue from that point on.  These are a mix of GUI applications and console applications.  This seems to be limited only to projects that I've imported from VS 2010 - I've never had this occur for applications created in VS 2015.

For one of these projects, I've gone through the process of removing all external libraries and reducing the source to a single file containing only the following:

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main(int, char**)
{
    return 0;
}
```

I even unchecked the "Inherit from parent or project defaults" button.  None of this has any effect - I still continue to get this exception.

If I compile any of these projects with VS 2010, the problem disappears -- until I compile with VS 2015 again.  In VS 2015, changing the Platform Toolset has no effect, either.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT:  Incorrectly wrote VS 2005 when it should have read VS 2010

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio will load `sysfer.dll` (from Symantec CMC Firewall) when running the program.

From the log you copied here, It looks like `sysfer.dll` is a problem here.

It is actually a first chance exception.

Disable loading `sysfer.dll`, use `regedit` to set the following registry to `4`:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SysPlant]
"Start"=dword:00000004
```

Reboot after changing the regedit.

Comment: This sounds promising, however I am unable to change this registry key (permission denied).  I cannot change the owner of the key, and I cannot make the change or change the owner when regedit is run at the system level with psexec.

Comment: Shutdown firewall service; does computer safe mode help in this case? I think you should be able change registry value in safe mode.